# (Mac OS X) Why is this process unkillable and its pid varies over time?

Tags: macos, process, terminal, pid, ps

Today when I tried to kill all the processes related to docker, I noticed something really funny:

```
➜  ~  ps aux | grep docker
Caesar          73944   0.0  0.0  2423372    220 s000  R+    6:49PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn docker
➜  ~  kill 73944
kill: kill 73944 failed: no such process
➜  ~  ps aux | grep docker
Caesar          74064   0.0  0.0  2432788    572 s000  R+    6:50PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn docker
➜  ~
```

I used ps aux | grep docker to find the process related to docker, although I am not sure if it is really a docker process. The funny thing is that: when I kill it using pid, I couldn't do it, as you can see from the screenshot. Also, I noticed that the pid changed at the second ps command.

I know the problem may look stupid, however, I couldn't find anything on Google because I didn't know how to describe it. Maybe you can help me with that. Thanks ; )

## Update

Thanks for the comments under this question. I noticed that the pid belongs to the grep process, and no wonder why the pids differ each time. Thank y'all for the help!

Comment: The different pid tells you that it's a different process. When you killed the first one, the parent probably noticed (or some other monitor) and simply restarted it (resulting in a new pid).

Comment: **Look** at the `ps` output. You're seeing the `grep` process that you're running in the pipeline. It's gone when the pipeline is finished, so of course you can't kill it.

Comment: @johnelemans I tested again, and the only difference is that I didn't kill the first one, and I assume that the parent process doesn't restart the job. Here is what I got:       ➜  ~  ps aux | grep docker
Caesar          98794   ...
➜  ~  ps aux | grep docker
Caesar          98809   ...

Comment: @AndrewMedico How did I miss the 'grep' name! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing the `grep` process, not the `docker` process. Whenever you use `grep` to filter the output of `ps` you'll run into this issue. To avoid listing the `grep` process, the canonical solution is to put square brackets around the first character in the target process name:

```
ps aux | grep '[d]ocker'
```

Since the search string contains square brackets (which don't effectively alter the regular expression) it will no longer be a match for the regular expression itself when found in the name of the `grep` process.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! If people are searching how to 'kill grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox redis' >> this is the answer.